# Xamarin.Forms Using SQLite - How to update all data for a specific column?

Tags: xamarin.forms, updates, sqlite-net

I am working on an XForms app (with sqlite) that uses aync methods. The DB has columns: ID, Name, Description, and boolValue. I  wanted to update a specific column (the boolValue) only and tried the following but it only updates, the current selection.

`enter code here`public Task UpdateChecked(ItemList item)
`enter code here`{
`enter code here`for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
`enter code here`{
`enter code here`if (item.ID == i)
`enter code here`{
`enter code here`bool val = false;
`enter code here`item.Done = val;
`enter code here`}
`enter code here`}
`enter code here`return Database.UpdateAsync(item);
`enter code here`}

How can I update all rows of the boolValue column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a query

```
Database.Execute("UPDATE TABLE SET Done = false");
```

Comment: J, Many thanks. It worked well.... Database.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE TABLE SET Done = false");